# Regenerate Docusign emails

Tags: docusignapi

I need to regenerate all of the DocuSign emails that have been sent out over the last couple of years.

I understand I cannot perfectly regenerate these due to some of the links involved in the email, but I think I should be able to come close.

So far in our demo account, I've received all the recipients for our envelopes, identified the sender and created records for all the initial sent emails as well as any completed emails.

For completed records, I can generate a viewLink. I need some assistance in generating a link for those that are not completed at this time. Also, should I be concerned about the viewLinks not expiring or can I secure these with an access code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to resend the email to a recipient if the recipient has not yet signed.

See the `resend_envelope` query parameter for the [EnvelopeRecipients: update method.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/)